# Pundit: Authorize specific resource to differently named controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pundit

Let's say I am using the [Pundit gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pundit) for authorization.  I have the following controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_authorization
  ...

  private
  def check_authorization
    authorize :blog
  end
end
```

Pundit looks at the argument passed in, `:blog` and thus infers there is a `BlogPolicy` class.  It then looks for the corresponding action name with a question mark, such as: `BlogPolicy#index?`.

If I want to look up the authorization on a specific resource I would just do this for that `check_authorization` method:

```
  def check_authorization
    authorize @blog
  end
```

Again, no problem.  Pundit looks at the class of the resource, `Blog`, and then looks for the `BlogPolicy` class.

- Example: The app could call the `BlogPolicy#show?` method and pass in that `@blog` resource.

Here is the issue: what do I do when I want to authorize on a specific controller name AND authorize on a specific resource, but that resource does not sync up with the controller name?

Example:

```
class SomeOtherBlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :check_authorization
  ...

  private
  def check_authorization
    authorize :some_other_blog, @blog
  end
end
```

The above code doesn't work, but hopefully it shows what I am trying to do.  Lets pretend this is happening on `SomeOtherBlogsController#show` action.

- I am trying to have pundit find the `SomeOtherBlogPolicy#show?` method,
- Within that Policy method, I want to check the authorization access of the `@blog` resource as well.

Hopefully the issue is apparent.  Since the resource class does not sync up with the controller name, It seems I am not able to do the above. So If I have the same resource used in various different controllers, I'm out of luck.  I wouldn't be able to check authorization of the resource in those various controller contexts.  Is this impossible to do with Pundit?

**Update**:

In the controller, I have also attempted to directly call the Policy method like so:

```
SomeOtherBlogPolicy.new(current_user, @blog).show?
```

However, calling that raised a `Pundit::AuthorizationNotPerformedError`.  So it appears that more happens in that `authorize` method than just returning `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually specify the resource class for a model by:

```
class Blog
  def self.policy_class
    SomeOtherBlogPolicy
  end
end
```

<del>Unfortunately its not possible to specify the policy class from the controller when calling `authorize`...</del>

This was true when I originally wrote the answer. v2.00 added a `policy_class` option to authorize:

```
authorize(@blog, policy_class: SomeOtherBlogPolicy)
```

So the workaround in my original answer is no longer needed.

Comment: since https://github.com/varvet/pundit/commit/1f93b8bfb19c6ca12a2da0319f4a193e618e7a19#diff-43022d52f798af4abc72a2783a87cd51 it's possible to override with ` authorize @publication, policy_class: PublicationPolicy`

Answer (score 3):

This is now a built in feature in Pundit Version `2.0.0.`  The documentation is updated with the following:

> You can pass an argument to override the policy class if necessary. For example:

```
def create
  @publication = find_publication # assume this method returns any model that behaves like a publication
  # @publication.class => Post
  authorize @publication, policy_class: PublicationPolicy
  @publication.publish!
  redirect_to @publication
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to override the policy class in the view as well? I tried doing this but got an error `unknown keyword: :policy_class`

```
<% if policy(@publication, policy_class: PublicationPolicy).create? %>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your use case, but one thing I've done is this: `<% if policy(:publication).my_custom_policy_in_application_policy? %>`.  Basically: I put customized policies within `ApplicationPolicy` and it is accessible from all my other policies because they all inherit from `ApplicationPolicy`.  The issue of course is if your authorization is based on the actual `@publication` record, then this won't work for you.